# MDX query to get distinct TOP N from sub-level?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am struggling to get an MDX query to select the TOP N from a sub-level.

In the following dataset, I'm trying to get the Salesman and top Sales Amount each day (highlighted) - note that "Ben" does not have any sales data until the last day: -

[image: Data]

So what I'd Like to see is this: -

[image: Correct Results]

I looked at this post "[Generate, TopCount, and All Others](https://martinmason.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/generate-topcount-and-all-others/)" and created this query: -

```
WITH
SET [DateTime2Set] AS ([Time].[Day].&[20171101]:[Time].[Day].&[20171106])

SET [Sales Guys] AS [Sales Persons].MEMBERS

SET [TopSales] AS
GENERATE(
    DateTime2Set,
    TopCount(
        EXISTING [Sales Guys],
        1,
        [Sales Amount]
    )
)

SELECT 
{
    [Sales Amount]
}
ON 0,

{
NonEmpty(
    (
        [DateTime2Set],
        [TopSales]
    )
    ,[Sales Amount]
)
}

 ON 1

FROM [Cube]
```

When I run the query I get the following results, with an unexpected item (highlighted)

[image]

So what is happening is that the top items per day are being added to an overall set which is then being joined onto the days.

This is not what I require.
I tried adding the crossjoin as described in the [MSDN documentation for the MDX Generate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/generate-mdx) like this: -

```
SET [TopSales] AS
GENERATE(
    DateTime2Set,
    TopCount(
        [Time].[Day].CURRENTMEMBER * [Sales Guys],
        1,
        [Sales Amount]
    )
)
```

But just get the error:-

> The Day hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function

How can I change the query to get the results that I need?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I worked it out finally.

```
SET [TopSales] AS
GENERATE(
    DateTime2Set,
    TopCount(
        DateTime2Set.CURRENTMEMBER * EXISTING Tags,
        1,
        [Sales Amount]
    )
)

SELECT 
{
    [Sales Amount]
}
ON 0,

{
NonEmpty(
    (
        [TopSales]
    )
    ,[Sales Amount]
)
}

ON 1

FROM [EventsCube]
```

I just removed DateTime2Set from the Columns and crossjoined DateTime2Set in the [Top Sales] calculated member